# Fan death in Korean and outside Korean

Tags: environmental-health

I have been reading some articles about [Fan Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_death) as a commonly held belief in Korea, although these days the younger generation seem to be dismissing it now for the myth that it had always been. I have not had any experience in the past of Korean people mentioning about this when they have been overseas, so is this something that is only commonly believed by South Korean people of the older generation and not the younger people that I would have met as overseas students in foreign countries.

Comment: It is not a disputed fact (that this is a myth). I am interested in whether people have experienced this outside of South Korea or only in the country itself.